# Trying to understand §7.2/6 in C++14

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer

7.2/6 (C++14):

> An enumeration whose underlying type is fixed is an incomplete type
>   from its point of declaration (3.3.2) to immediately after its
>   *enum-base* (if any), at which point it becomes a complete type. An enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed is an incomplete type
>   from its point of declaration to immediately after the closing } of
>   its *enum-specifier*, at which point it becomes a complete type.

Take a look at the snippet below (see [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbf1ab6b7984f7eb)):

```
enum A{} t;                 // enum A{} is a complete type (OK)
enum class B:int z;         // enum class B:int is not a complete type
int main()
{
}
```

I understand why `B` is not a complete type. But, by just looking at the paragraph above, this doesn't seem so clear to me. `z` is declared right after the *enum-base* of an enumeration, whose underlying type is fixed, the same way `t`is declared right after the closing `}` of the *enum-specifier* of an enumerator whose underlying type is not fixed.

Comment: It's not that it isn't a complete type. It's that the grammar doesn't allow you to declare a variable there.

Comment: What are you asking? I see no question in your post.

Comment: @T.C. It compiles in [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xal8i4yviOMrr1LF), but not in gcc. Wouldn't it still make sense to compile though because `B` is an incomplete type?

Comment: Not that it changes anything, but your live example uses the C++11 flag.

Comment: @TC `It's that the grammar doesn't allow you to declare a variable there.` Could you elaborate?

Comment: `enum class B` seems to me as a complete type because it has fixed type (the type is specified as per 7.2/5) and the enum-base (which is just the underlying type specifier as per 7.2/1) is specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that `B` isn't complete. As shown in your own quote, it is complete immediately after its *enum-base*, `: int`. The problem is that you are using a construct that the grammar doesn't allow.

The *type-specifier* production allows two ways in which the keyword `enum` can appear in it ([dcl.type]):

1. in an *elaborated-type-specifier*.
2. in an *enum-specifier*.

An *elaborated-type-specifier* containing `enum` looks like ([dcl.type.elab])

> `enum` *nested-name-specifier<sub>opt</sub> identifier*

which doesn't fit your code, and moreover cannot declare a new type (see [basic.lookup.elab]/p2). That is, while `struct A* pa;` is legal even without a previous declaration of `A`, `enum B * pb;` is not legal.

An *enum-specifier* ([dcl.enum]/p1) is one of

> *enum-head* `{` *enumerator-list<sub>opt</sub>* `}` 
>   *enum-head* `{` *enumerator-list* `,` `}`

without digging into what *enum-head* is, it is obvious this requires braces, which isn't in your code.

`enum class B : int;` is an *opaque-enum-declaration*, whose grammar is

> *enum-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier enum-base<sub>opt</sub>* `;`

This doesn't allow you to declare anything other than the enum itself.

In short, the grammar simply doesn't allow `enum class B:int z;`. Instead, you can write `enum class B:int; B z;`, which is perfectly valid, though the `: int` is redundant.

Comment: It took me sometime to grasp what's going on here. Great answer. Thanks (+1).

Comment: As [0x499602D2](http://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2) mentioned above, clang has a bug here, for it compiles the snippet in my question. Also GCC states (incorrectlly) in it's error message that the type `B` is incomplete.

Comment: @Belloc GCC never said anything about `B` being incomplete.

Comment: You're right. I've got confused with my own comment.